# issues with eclipse shortcut key

Tags: php, html, eclipse

The eclipse shortcut key `alt + shift + up` which is used to select enclosed element is working fine with `.html` file but doesn't work with the html code wrotten in `.php` file.
How do I fix it. OR is there any other alternative to select the content between the html tags?